# algebra exponents and fractions

Tags: fractions

I could be over thinking or tired... But I am to embarrassed to ask my prof. this probably very simple algebra rule I am ignorant of... Also this is just a snip-it from a inductive proof example.

```
Say you have something like this
```

$${\frac{4^k - 1}{3}} +{\frac{3*4^k}{3}} =$$
$${\frac{4*4^k-1}{3}}$$
My question is what algebra rules or rules of fractions allow this? In other words what computation is going on? I can agree that the 3 should cancel out
 $${\frac{3*4^k}{3} =} {{4^k}}$$
But wouldn't that mean it be something like this
$${\frac{(4^k-1)*4^k}{3}}$$
or more accurately
 $${\frac{(4^k-1)}{3}{* 4^k}}$$
and not this?
$${\frac{4*4^k-1}{3}}$$

Comment: I'm not sure which part you are asking about. But $u+3u=4u$ So $4^x+3 \cdot 4^x=4 \cdot 4^x$.

Comment: Wait are you talking about how do you combine fractions?

Comment: $\frac{u(x)}{3}+c=\frac{u(x)}{3}+\frac{3c}{3}=\frac{u(x)+3c}{3}$. We are able to do this because $c=\frac{n}{n}c, n \neq 0$. Like you know since $\frac{n}{n}=1 \text{ where } n \neq 0$

Comment: @randomgirl I guess It would be about exponent rules. 
And so 10*11^x = 11?

Comment: It sounds like you are wondering how they combined like terms now? But yeah no $10 \cdot 11^x \neq 11$

Comment: Its the Distributive law $a(b + c) = ab + ac$
$$ 4^{k}\cdot4 = 4^{k}\cdot(1 + 3) = 4^{k} + 3\cdot4^{k}  $$

Comment: @randomgirl I am sorry I don't have the mathematical vocabulary to explain what it is I am asking well... So $${4^x + 3*4^x = 4*4^x}$$ but $${3⋅4^x} {≠} {4}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${\frac{4^k - 1}{3}} +{\frac{3\cdot4^k}{3}} \\ \text{ these fractions have the same denominator so we can write the fraction as one now } \\ \frac{4^k-1+3 \cdot 4^k}{3} \\ \text{ recall } u+3u=4u \\ \text{ so we have } \\ \frac{4^k(1+3)-1}{3}=\frac{4^k (4)-1}{3}=\frac{4 \cdot 4^k-1}{3}=\frac{4^{k+1}-1}{3} \\ $

Comment: Oh my God! I need to take a break from math - yes I see it now. Thanks. I will make this the answer.

Comment: I was starting to lose my mind thinking that $${4^x + 3*4^x = 4*4^x}$$ meant $${3⋅4^x} {=} {4}$$